# Removing the jquery/zepto dependency on backbone.router and views

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, backbone.js, client-side

Is there a forked/maintained version of backbone that completely eliminates the need for jquery or zepto to use both the router and views?

I wouldn't mind using backbone but there's no way in heck I'd force a jquery dependency on my page just to use it.

If a solution doesn't exist can someone post a gist of what needs to be changed exactly?

Comment: Given that the event handling system for views is based on `$.delegate` and friends, I think you're very much out of luck.

Comment: Indeed. :/ [character limitation]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want Backbone to handle DOM manipulation, DOM events, and AJAX requests, then you'll need another library to do this. It doesn't have to be jQuery or Zepto - Backbone also supports Ender, and you could theoretically use any library that can do DOM selection and supports a subset of jQuery-style methods. A quick look through the [annotated source code](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html) shows that you need the following methods:

- `$(selector)`
- `$.ajax()`
- `$(selector).find()`
- `$(selector).bind()`
- `$(selector).unbind()`
- `$(selector).delegate()`
- `$(selector).remove()`
- `$(selector).attr()`
- `$(selector).html()`

If you don't want Backbone to deal with this stuff, you can pretty easily remove the requirements by overwriting the methods that use them - e.g. you can dispense with `.attr()` and `.html()` by setting `Backbone.View.prototype.make = function() {}`. Or just don't use `Backbone.View` - that removes the need for everything but `$.ajax()` (unless you're using `pushState`, in which case you need event binding too).

Comment: Ok thanks, so basically it's not worth the effort? That seems like an awful lot of overriding to do manually. -- Edit: Going to let this run for a few more hours and mark you as correct if no solutions are given.

Comment: Well, as I said, just don't use `Backbone.View`. Then you only have to implement `$.ajax()`. If you're not willing to use a DOM library, you won't get much value out of `Backbone.View` anyway.

Comment: I disagree with that. It's not too crazy to think of selecting an element by using getElementById() instead of using jquery, or setting the innerHTML attribute of something, etc..

Comment: Right - but the point is, `Backbone.View` is pretty light ("more covention than code," per the docs), and almost all of the [methods](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View) require a DOM library. The biggest support the class offers is event handling, which is possible to re-implement, but a pain. Take away all that stuff and you're left with a class you could write yourself in 10 minutes, plus some best practice conventions.

Answer (score 4):

Yup here's one: https://github.com/inkling/backbone.native. It's a tiny adapter that allows Backbone to work while relying on only native DOM APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [jBone](https://github.com/kupriyanenko/jbone), this is library for DOM manipulations in modern browsers, jBone developed special for Backbone, only 2kb gzipped and jQuery like API.