# Minimum JQuery modules required by Backbone

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

As it's now possible to build custom version of JQuery with only the modules you require, I assumed it would be easy to find out what the requirements for Backbone are, but I can't seem to find the information.

What are the minimum JQuery modules required to enable full functionality in Backbone?

Or to put it another way, which modules can be excluded from a JQuery build without affecting Backbone at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by @nrabinowitz in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10016470/706246), you need the following methods:

- `$(selector)`
- `$.ajax()`
- `$(selector).find()`
- `$(selector).bind()`
- `$(selector).unbind()`
- `$(selector).delegate()`
- `$(selector).remove()`
- `$(selector).attr()`
- `$(selector).html()`

So reading the [modules](https://github.com/jquery/jquery#modules) definition of jQuery I would say you need **core** and **selector** that can't be excluded, plus the **ajax** module.

Comment: Thank you Puigcerber. I'm not sure I would have found the right search terms to find that.

Comment: I'll take a look at this over the next few days.

Comment: I've done a quick test using the Backbone todo app. It seems ajax and css are the only optional JQuery modules that are required.

Comment: But that's because they use `toogle()`, `show()` and `hide()`. Backbone itself doesn't require the **css** module.